# Do the Solutions to Integrals Depend on Which Side has the Constant?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to solve the following integral problem:
$\int$$\frac{dx}{x}$ $=$ $\int[\frac{1}{y-1}-\frac1y]$$dy$. Applying the integral should yield: $\ln\lvert x\rvert$ $=$ $\ln\lvert y-1\rvert$ - $\ln\lvert y\rvert$ $+$ $C$. I then raised the right hand side to $e$ so I could obtain $\lvert x \rvert$. It looks like this: $\lvert x\rvert$ $=$ $e^{{(\ln\lvert y-1\rvert}/\ln\lvert y\rvert) +C} $ After simplifying the $ln$ terms raised to a power and getting rid of the absolute value signs I get: $C\frac{y-1}{y} = x$ In solving for $y$ I get $y$ = $\frac{C}{C-x}$. The correct solution is $\frac{1}{1-Cx}$. I checked to see if my solution is equivalent, but it is not. In the work of this problem it appears that the solver put $C$ on the side of $\ln\lvert x\rvert$, -- the opposite side of my constant. Why do these two ways yield different results and why is my way of solving incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

It the same, just divide numerator and denominator by $C$:
$$
y=\frac{C}{C-x} = \frac{C/C}{C/C - x/C} = \frac{1}{1-x/C}
$$

Since $C$ is just an integration constant, $K = 1/C$ would be an integration constant as well, so
$$
y=\frac{1}{1-Kx}
$$
would be a equivalent form.

Comment: Good to substitute $K=1/C$ like this.  Sometimes, however, $C=0$ and/or $K=0$ must be allowed, complicating this simplification.

Comment: @GEdgar yes :) you have to be very careful then... but here $C=0$ implies $y=0$, unlikely the desirable answer

Answer (score 0):

Obviously not,

$$f(x)+c=g(y)\text{ and }f(x)=g(y)+c$$

are identical, but for the sign of $c$, which is arbitrary.

Comment: You will tell me that the difference you observed isn't just a change of sign. It indeed is, as you take the exponential: $e^{-c}=1/e^c$.